# Is it possible to copy and paste hidden contents in Excel with the same contents staying hidden after pasting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I was wondering whether it was possible to copy an area in Excel 2016 that contains hidden rows or columns to another empty worksheet, while keeping the same rows and columns hidden?

In other words: after pasting the same rows and columns should stay hidden.

Comment: > By default, Excel copies hidden or filtered cells in addition to visible cells. [Quoted from here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Copy-visible-cells-only-6e3a1f01-2884-4332-b262-8b814412847e)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to do this by Pasting the content twice, using Paste Special.

The first time Paste Special Values

The second time Paste Special Column widths

[image]

Comment: Can't you choose both values and column widths and do it in one step?

Comment: Not in the version I tried. It doesn't appear to be possible when I tried